# Как можно оптимизировать запрос выборки по двум датам из БД Sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Составил запрос по выборке максимальных значений из двух полей с датами, используя несколько связанных таблиц:

```
SELECT mes.measureCommFromTab, p.XMLizmerenije, p.XMLdatetime, p.measureComm_id
 FROM `xmlmessagetab` p
INNER JOIN `indexobjectstab` ps ON ps.keyID = p.indexObjectsTab_id
INNER JOIN `measurecommtab` mes ON mes.keyID = p.measureComm_id
WHERE ps.indexObject = '55285'
  AND p.XMLdatetime = (SELECT max(p.XMLdatetime)
                         FROM `xmlmessagetab` p
                        INNER JOIN `indexobjectstab` ps
                           ON ps.keyID = p.indexObjectsTab_id
                        WHERE ps.indexObject = '55285')
  AND p.datetimeMess = (SELECT max(p.datetimeMess) 
                          FROM `xmlmessagetab` p
                         INNER JOIN `indexobjectstab` ps
                            ON ps.keyID = p.indexObjectsTab_id
                         WHERE ps.indexObject = '55285')
```

Запрос выполняется две с половиной минуты, что невыносимо долго.

1. Подскажите, может быть есть способ оптимизировать данный запрос?
2. Есть план "Б": при записи данных в БД, дублировать последнюю дату поля "XMLdatetime" и потом использовать её для составления запроса на выборку по последней дате, что скажете об этом варианте?

Comment: Проверьте. допускает ли SQLite синтаксис `AND (p.XMLdatetime, p.datetimeMess) = ( SELECT max(p.XMLdatetime), max(p.datetimeMess) FROM ... )`? Ну и с индексами покрутитесь... *что скажете об этом варианте?* Да хреновенький вариант-то.

Comment: Нет, не принимает такую конструкцию:( "Ошибка в запросе; near ",": syntax error Unable to execute statement"

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен насчёт оптимальности, но мне кажется, что ваш запрос можно как минимум уменьшить до чего-то типа

```
SELECT mes.measureCommFromTab, p.XMLizmerenije, p.XMLdatetime, p.measureComm_id
  FROM `xmlmessagetab` p
 INNER JOIN `indexobjectstab` ps ON ps.keyID = p.indexObjectsTab_id
 INNER JOIN `measurecommtab` mes ON mes.keyID = p.measureComm_id
 WHERE ps.indexObject = '55285'
 GROUP BY ps.indexObject
HAVING p.XMLdatetime = MAX(p.XMLdatetime)
   AND p.datetimeMess = MAX(p.datetimeMess)
```

Comment: Разобрался с применением параметра "HAVING" и вроде как по логике ваш год и мой код, по логике вроде бы одинаковые, но при этом по вашему запросу выдается только одно значение "XMLizmerenije".

Comment: Пробовал так изменить " GROUP BY ps.indexObject, p.XMLdatetime, p.datetimeMess", фигня получается...